# How to create a new column in each dataframe? The new column must show the tab name as each row in the new column

Tags: python

The new column Emp_no should show L&D1 in for the first loop(first dataframe) and L&D2(second dataframe) in the second

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('sheet2.xlsx')

i = 1
name = 'L&D'
for x in range(2):
    string = name + str(i)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, string)
    df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
    df1['Emp_No'] = string
    df1 = df1.append(df1)
    int(i)
    i = i + 1
    
df1
```

Currently the output for all rows is L&D2 in column 'Emp_no' but it should be showing the first loops data as L&D1 and the second loop as L&D2

Sample L&D1 & L&D2(sheet names) - This is the desired output=

```
Name    Section  MVAL    SVAL   Emp_No(To be created)
string  string    int    int      L&D1    - FROM sheet 1
string  string    int    int     L&D1   - FROM sheet 1
string  string    int    int      L&D2  - From sheet 2
string  string    int    int      L&D2  - From sheet 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure i understand the question, but if im not mistaken you're trying to go from something like this?

```
dict_1 = {
    "names" : "john jane joe jake".split(" "),
    "Unnamed_0" : "25 30 32 45".split(),
    "pos" : "ceo cfo admin janitor".split(),
    "Unnamed_1": "ff oo bb aa".split()
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)

names   Unnamed_0   pos Unnamed_1
0   john    25     ceo      ff
1   jane    30     cfo      oo
2   joe     32     admin    bb
3   jake    45    janitor   aa
```

To this?

```
rename_cols = ["L&D"+str(i+1) for i in range(2)]

old_cols = list(df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')].columns)

mapper = dict(zip(old_cols, rename_cols))

new_df = df.rename(columns=mapper)

new_df

names L&D1      pos L&D2
0  john   25      ceo   ff
1  jane   30      cfo   oo
2   joe   32    admin   bb
3  jake   45  janitor   aa
```

Let me know. More info could definitely be helpful if this doesn't help.

Comment: Hey @jakemoyo, I have added more to my question. I would like to join the two tabs in excel and create the new column Emp_No and have the tab name as a column name

Comment: What you added to your post does not seem to match what you're saying though, I'm actually more confused now. I would recommend trying to post again with a simplified version of what you're attempting and a clear expected result.

Comment: I have edited it again, by incrementing the Int 'i' the 'string' changes when entering the for loop by L&D1 to L&D2 which is correct. However, when appended to the dataframe the columns seem to all remain as L&D2